# Why can't I remote debug? How could I find out why?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, debugging, remote-debugging

If one can't connect for remote debugging with a java process how could this issue be "debugged"?
There is no firewall
I can connect to remote debugger but not always. I mean if I connect and disconnect, it is not possible to reconnect again;

Is there a way to debug this?  Does java have any logs for this?

Comment: Are the debugger and the debuggee running on the same machine? Do you get any error messages when trying to reconnect?

Comment: @Andreas:No.Different machine.Java to be debugged in linux box.Eclipse running in Windows

Comment: What error do you get when you try to reconnect? Maybe you have no disconnected properly.

Comment: @m3th0dman:Error reported in eclipse is: `Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection timed out.org.eclipse.jdi.TimeoutException`

Comment: It is possible that you have not disconnected properly; or if the server is remote someone else is already connected. I would suggest restarting the server and try then.

Comment: @m3th0dman:What do you mean by not disconnecting properly?I do `Terminate` from eclipse

Answer (score 3):

Can you check on the debug port that is configured in the remote machine and the one you are trying to use is same ? This might be one possible case.

If you didn't configure a debug port try configuring it. Your call will always be routed through that port instead of default/random port handled by your server.

Here is an example for how I do for weblogic

```
set JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4529,server=y,suspend=n
```

Comment: This is not really a suitable answer, it is a comment, but I realised you currently are not able to comment

Comment: @thecoshman what do you mean by comment ?? did I not say that it might be one possible case ??

Comment: So sorry, I miss understood what you had said, at first it seemed like you where just guessing at things.